# Grep /var/log/maillog for email to a certain user, based only on his linux username

Tags: centos, grep, logs, postfix

I have a learning environment, based on Linux CentOS, with Postfix and SquirrelMail running, but my assignment is more in general.

I need to find in the maillog e-mails **received by** a certain user within a certain time frame, based **only** on his Linux username.

I see my maillog, but I am not experienced in reading maillog and I have two concerns:

1. Whether or not these patterns that I see in the log are something reliable, i.e. whether a log for incoming e-mail will always have `to=<EMAIL>` in it.

   ```
   Jan 2 20:31:17 tmcent01 postfix/local[27450]: B58C4330038: to=<root@tmcent01.training5.tm>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=9.7, delays=9.6/0.03/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
   ```
2. How does a Linux username correspond to the e-mail name of the user? It is not it always a match (username@domain), is it? We could have alias for it, how can I take this in consideration when composing the Regex for the `grep`?

My first two attempts were a strike-out.

```
sudo grep "to=<jsmith@" /var/log/maillog | grep 1[2-4]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
sudo grep -w "jsmith" /var/log/maillog | grep 1[2-4]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple sample script for you to try. It will search for user's aliases from the common /etc/aliases -file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Arguments: 
# $1 = user name to be searched for
# $2 = location for e-mail log file

# First, let's create a temporary working directory.
WORKDIR=$(mktemp -d)
cd "${WORKDIR}" || exit

# Create a file for user's user name and all aliases.
echo "to=<""$1" > search_key.txt

# Then, let's find out possible alises for the user.
# Awk is used just to separate the first column.
grep "$1" /etc/aliases | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" }; {print "to=<" $1}' >> search_key.txt

# Next, search for e-mails sent for all these.
grep -f search_key.txt "$2"

# Finally, remove the working directory.
rm -rf "${WORKDIR}"

# All done.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is a fixed assignment, it must be done with grep.

Comment: If you can use only grep, then it is a bit difficult for you, in case you need to search for aliases also. But for the first question, just searching for "to=<username" should be sufficient, i.e.
    grep "to=<johndoe" /var/log/mail.log

Comment: OP looks on the right track... and the pointer to the aliases looks a step in the right direction too.... I would suggest looking at the documentation about how aliases are defined and try `grep`ing the logfile with the output of `grep -Po "[^:]*(?=:.*jsmith@.*)" \etc\aliases` as well as the username....

Answer (score 0):

> Whether or not these patterns that I see in the log are something reliable, i.e. whether a log for incoming e-mail will always have to= in it

Yes any email processed by Postfix will have an entry with to=... but this will include emails which are not delivered locally. Also, be aware that the mailbox part in the email address is not necessarily the same as a single local user - Postfix may apply expansion/replacement to this, and the MDA may apply expansion/replacement to this.

The only reliable mechanism to capture the information you seem to want would be to instrument the MDA, not the MTA.